# Trying to identify and move pdf files listed in txt file from source'a' to dest'b' from batch script?

Tags: batch-file, filesize, last-modified

I want to move few 100 pdf files to another directory from a source containing 1000s pdf. I have text file which has all the pdf file names listed in separate lines. Program has to read the file name from the text file and find that in source folder, if the file size is 12 KB and is older than 2014, Move it to destination 'b'.
Im working on windows 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont mind using powershell :

```
#variables initialisation
$filelist=c:\temp\list.txt
$source="c:\temp\pdf"
$destination="c:\temp2"

#read the content of yout list
$files=get-content $filelist 

#will process the following instructions for all the filename in filelist
$files | foreach { 
    $f=get-childitem $source -filter "$_" -recurse #try to find the file in sourcedir
    if( (($f.size /1KB) -eq 12) -and ($f.lastwritetime.year -lt 2014)){ #check if size is 12KB and last modification time occured before 2014
        move-item $_.fullname $destination #move the file
    }
}
```

Comment: Im a very much starter in powershell, but this looks simple and easy though, let me try that and get back.

Comment: copy/ paste the code in a .ps1 file, then right click and select run with powershell

Comment: It throws error saying I cant execute scripts"File C:\Users\E843608\Desktop\powershell.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:0 char:0" How should I enable that??

Comment: right click on powershell shortcut, start it as administrator and run the following : `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

Batch file to extract file names from input file:

`for /f %%i in (InputFile.txt) do call bat2.bat %%i`

Batch file to get file size:

`for %%i in (%1.txt) do echo %%~zi`

...and continue from here

Comment: I have a text file which has pdf names: a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf. all are in new lines,I want to find each pdf file in a folder where more than 100 files are there.criteria is it should be of 12kb and last modified date earlier to 2014.

Comment: Please take help on the above command (run `for /?`), and you will be able to continue with the task. The sample supplied here should get you starting. It enumerate file names from 'InputFile.txt' and extract each file size.

Comment: What will be there in bat2.bat file?

Comment: The second 'for' line (Batch file to get file size)

Comment: HI can you get me code to extract file-names from a folder which has "the page cannot be found"